# Making catenary curve(line) using two points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to create line feature with certain interval(small) so that line looks like curve using **catenary** formula. The given parameters are X, Y coordinate of two electric poles and need to create the hanging wire looking curve using line feature with interval. The formula for catenary is
[image]

```
y = a cosh(x/a)
```

where a is already known. How can we generate points and make line segment?

Comment: Do you have sample coordinates and the corresponding `a` value? That way it'd be easier to come up with an answer.

Comment: x coordinate list is [198843.66147726047, 198932.04957524478, 199020.4376732291, 199108.82577121342, 199197.21386919773, 199285.60196718207, 199373.99006516638, 199462.3781631507, 199550.76626113502, 199639.15435911933] and value of a is 752.921146267743 . Using above formula of catenary curve and generated y values are not valid Y coordinates .So, I just want to generate catenary curve coordinates . For demo we may use any data set.

Comment: "Using above formula of catenary curve and generated y values are not valid Y coordinates". Don't really get how this should work in the end. I suggest you to add a complete example in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a detailed look at your picture, you can observe that **a** value, based in formulation 2 of this [reference](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equation_of_Catenary), is 20 so, 752.921146267743 has not sense even in feet (229.490365382 m).

If you want to applied catenary formulation, you have to consider that y values are really z values (in this case, for electric poles, 30 meters high and 40 meters apart). Following script exemplifies the process.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 20

x = range(-20, 21, 1)

z = [ a*math.cosh(ele/a) for ele in x ]

plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()  # Create a figure containing a single axes.

ax.plot(x, z)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

ax.set_ylim(ymin = 0)
ax.set_ylabel('z')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_title("z values for catenary") # Add a title to the axes.
```

After running above script, you have following result:

[image]

Final path is to convert (X,Y) coordinates between two electric poles in a Z-line (X,Y,Z). The catenary seen from above between two electric poles (in your SIG system) it will be a straight line; not a catenary.

Comment: Thanks Xunilk .Above answer helped  alot. The main thing that I am confused is about value of "a" .As example you have considered "a" = 20. Is there any specific reason for selecting this value ? The another problem is that  does the value of "a" depends on the coordinate range. My coordinate range is of x is [198843.66 ,...,199639.15] taken from QGIS canvas and real value for "a" is 752. How can we create smooth catenary curve with these values? Thanks in advance.